# entities() crashes with PrimitiveType != null error

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, telerik

I'm using model first and i don't have any edmmetadata table also got this error when i converted my project to Telerik MVC

> Assertion failed
>
> Expression: primitiveType != null
>
> Description: Assertion failed: primitiveType != null

it happens here

`public DigikalaHREntities()
            : base("name=DigikalaHREntities")
        {
        }`

I've read other google  google pages but nothing is similar to mine